# my function variable reset when I call function javascript

Tags: javascript

I making scroll animation progress bars, when the scroll reaches the element's width change from  0 to 78%. but there is one problem whenever I scroll again in the same height condition my width reset.
I know why this happens. in fact, the range variable(i comment in JS) reassigns to 0 whenever I scroll, I don't know how to fix it. I read about Closures but couldn't understand how I must apply that to my code
thanks for reading and for your time

```js
//my js code
const SEORange = document.getElementById("SEO");


window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  let top = SEORange.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let range = 0;  // the problem is here range will be reset 
  //whenever I scroll
  if (top < window.innerHeight * 0.905) {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (range == 78) {
        clearInterval;
      } else {
        range++;
        SEORange.style.width = range + "%";
      }
    }, 10);
  }
});
```

```css
/*css file*/
*{
height:100vh  /*I add some height to see what happen if scroll*/

}
#section2-text-container {
  justify-content: end;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

#section2-text-container form {
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.range-container {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 8px;
  position: relative;
}
#section2-text-container input {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #64bfd2;
  width: 0;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0 5% 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
}

#section2-text-container input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 0px;
  background: #010101;
  height: 0px;
}
#section2-text-container input::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 0px;
  background: #04aa6d;

}
```

```html
 <!--html file-->
 
 
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body> 
   <div id="section2-text-container">

       <form>
          <label for="SEO">SEO</label><br><br>
          <div class="range-container">
          <input id="SEO" disabled type="range" value="0" />
         </div>
        </form>
        
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to change the width of the element just once? Btw, [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) is a function which you should call with the interval id. And you probably can do the animation by assigning a class to the element, instead of setting the height width value using javascript.

Comment: @c0m1t there is no need set a parameter for clearInterval when using it inside the Interval anyway clearInterval cause width stop at  78 and don't go to infinity

Comment: @c0m1t  I want change the width just once and when scroll reaches the element

Comment: That has to create tons of intervals

Comment: Whenever `scroll` event is triggered, you set the `range` to zero. Maybe read the value of range using by getting the width of your element?  See [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) documentation. It is a function and requires an interval id as a parameter. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-flower-mbdnzu?file=/src/index.js) is a code which does not call `clearInterval` or call it with no argument and as you can see, the interval is not cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to make sure that you clear the interval, because 'scroll' event will be fired multiple times each second when the user scrolls.

```
const SEORange = document.getElementById("SEO");
let intervalId;
let range = 0;

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  let top = SEORange.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  // If intervalId is set, it means the code has been ran once.
  if (top < window.innerHeight * 0.905 && !intervalId) {
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (range === 78) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      } else {
        range++;
        SEORange.style.width = range + "%";
      }
    }, 10);
  }
})
```

Another solution would be to add a class to trigger the transition you want. Which is IMO way better(smoother) than setting the width using an interval.

```
const SEORange2 = document.getElementById("SEO2");

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  let top = SEORange.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  if (top < window.innerHeight * 0.905) {
    SEORange2.classList.add("animate");
  }
});
```

```
#SEO2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: width 780ms linear;
}

#SEO2.animate {
  width: 78%;
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-fog-i4u3vw?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: thanks for your answer if you remove clearInterval's parameter,  still works

Comment: If you either remove the parameter or remove the `clearInterval` it will still work. BUT the interval is not cleared. You can put a console log below/above the `clearInterval` and you will see that it will be logged every 10 ms.

Answer (score 0):

here I tried for 3 elements in one block of code. if anybody has a shorter solution share it with me
by helping @c0m1t

```js
const eagerToLearnRange = document.getElementById("eager-to-learn");
const frontEndRange = document.getElementById("front-end");
const SEORange = document.getElementById("SEO");


let intervalId;
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  let top = SEORange.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let range = 0;
  if (top < window.innerHeight * 0.905 && !intervalId) {
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (range <= 20) {
        range++;
        SEORange.style.width = range + "%";
        frontEndRange.style.width = range + "%";
        eagerToLearnRange.style.width = range + "%";
      } else if (65 >= range && range >= 20) {
        frontEndRange.style.width = range + "%";
        eagerToLearnRange.style.width = range + "%";
        range++;
      } else if (65 <= range && range <= 100) {
        eagerToLearnRange.style.width = range + "%";
        range++;
      } else if (range === 100) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    }, 10);
  }
});
```

```css
* { height:200vh /*add some height to show you effect */
}

#section2-text-container form {
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.range-container {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 8px;
  position: relative;
}
#section2-text-container input {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #64bfd2;
  width: 0;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0 5% 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
}

#section2-text-container input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}
#section2-text-container input::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;

}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="section2-text-container">
     <form>
        <label for="eager-to-learn">eager to learn</label>   <br/><br/>
        <div class="range-container">
           <input id="eager-to-learn" disabled type="range" value="0" >
         </div>
 <br><br>
         <label for="front-end">front-end</label><br><br>
          <div class="range-container">
            <input id="front-end" disabled type="range" value="0"/>
          </div>
 <br><br>
          <label for="SEO">SEO</label>
<br><br>
          <div class="range-container">
            <input id="SEO" disabled type="range" value="0"/>
         </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```